# How do I set an image for Facebook to use in links to Mediawiki pages

Tags: facebook, mediawiki

Links from Facebook to my Mediawiki-powered website show an ugly default image for links. (The squarish image which shows a truncated "Powered by Mediawiki") pointed to by the gray arrow.)[image]

How do I override this?  I'm looking for a single image which would be the same for all pages rather than a custom image for each page.  I want to avoid adding extensions if possible!

Added: #wgLogo is set and the logo file thus set does appear on the individual pages, but not on the FB link.

Comment: Have you set `$wgLogo`/`$wgLogos`/`$wgLogoHD`?

Comment: @Alexander Mashin: Yes. It is set and the logo appears correctly on the pages but not in FB links.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the secret is to set `<meta property='og:image'…` on every page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/images/).

To do so without installing extensions, add to your `LocalSettings.php`:

```php
$wgHooks ['BeforePageDisplay'] [] = function (OutputPage &$out, Skin &$skin): bool {
    $out->addMeta ('og:image', '(path to your image)');
    return true;
};
```

Further reading:

- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/BeforePageDisplay
- https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classOutputPage.html#a1d667167a39be62f9988e94256508489

Answer (score 1):

The [PageImages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageImages) extension adds the most prominent image used on the page as the OpenGraph image. The [WikiSEO](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WikiSEO) extension lets you set it manually (per-page or sitewide).